# Rails has_one relationship where foreign key is on owning model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

**I have a `Photo` and `Photoset` model:**

A `Photoset` should have many `photos` and one `primary_photo`.
A `Photo` should belong to many `Photosets` and can be the `primary_photo` of many photosets.

However I am stumped as how to setup the `primary_photo` relation. I was envisioning adding a `primary_photo_id` to `photosets` but I can't figure out how define the `has_one` so that the column is defined on the owning side (Photoset).

**I tried to implement this by:**

- Adding a `photo_photosets` join table.
- Adding a `primary_photo_id` column to `photosets`.

I setup up the relations in my models:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :photosets
  validates_uniqueness_of :flickr_uid
end

class Photoset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :flickr_uid
  has_and_belongs_to_many :photos
  has_one :primary_photo, class_name: 'Photo' # !???
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :photosets
      validates_uniqueness_of :flickr_uid
    end

    class Photoset < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      validates_uniqueness_of :flickr_uid
      has_and_belongs_to_many :photos
      belongs_to :primary_photo, class_name: 'Photo'
    end
```